# Accidenlty query deleted all records in couchbase how to recover that

Tags: couchbase

I am new to couchbase. 
i had lot of duplicate records in my bucket.
i tried to delete the repeating records but accidentally deleted all records.
i dont know how to retrieve the deleted records.
pls help me to get back the records or guide me to change the bucket to previous state

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that is possible if you don't have a dump of your data...

Answer (score 2):

Couchbase does not immediately erase the data from deleted documents. Instead, deleted documents are marked, and the space is later reclaimed. If the reclamation has not yet happened, it may be possible for you to manually recover the deleted documents from the underlying files. Shut down your server immediately though, so the reclamation doesn't happen inadvertently.

This article is a place to start:
https://blog.avira.com/recovering-couchbase-data-vbuckets/